# Anybody using iziModal.js on their projects?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I love the elegance of **iziModal.js** and I would like to switch to it on my website. However, during tests I'm having problems opening the modal. Everything works as it should except that the overlay opens on top of the modal window. Ive tried to fiddle with the css and the js but cannot make it happen. The only way you can interact with the modal window is by using "overlay: false" or change "zindex:" to a very high number like 9999999999999999999999999 both options opening the modal without overlay.
Can you help with this issue, please?

Example can be seen on
https://squareplate.co.uk/3
The website is still in development :)

Scroll down to the "Report error" and "Claim listing" area and click on the "modal" link to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Florin, Thank you for your feedback. This and other improvements you find in the next update of iziModal (v1.5.0). I promise it will be soon.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by enclosing the whole website content in a div with id body between `<body>` and `</body>` and change the iziModal.js from
`that.$overlay.appendTo('body');` to `that.$overlay.appendTo('#body');`
Now everything works great...